# Scroll on a div

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I work on the customization of a google map for a website. I managed to get what I wanted with the API and the site of [customization](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).

Currently, it is possible to scroll over my map to get closer or highter. I wonder if we could do the same on my div placed over my map (which contains a form) ?

*My map (the form is on the right):*
*remove*

Ps: I've pixelate the map for security reasons.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. The maps api exposes the methods `getZoom` and `setZoom` for that kind of thing. All you need to do is set up the event handler for the mousewheel event in your container.

It's going to look something like this:

```
$('#container').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
  var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
    map.setZoom(currentZoom + 1);
  }
  else {
    map.setZoom(currentZoom - 1);
  }
});
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tEz3L/) so you can see it in action.

Also, if you're trying to zoom in to a particular point, you can use `setCenter` before you do the zoom. The point you select as your center will be the point that the map zooms in towards.

Comment: Hi ! Thx for your help but I'm not sure that you understand what I was thinking. So when we are on my form, I wanted that you can scroll up/down the map like if my mouse was on the map.

Comment: Oh i see. So you essentially want to extend the area of the map to include your form?

Comment: Exactly ! Is that possible ?

Comment: Yeah, probably. Hang on, I'll see if I can throw something together

Comment: @Drupal8ForTheWin I edited my answer and provided a jsfiddle to show you how it can be done. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi! Thx for the answer. Well,I don't what's the problem... I'have copy/past your code on a test file and nothing work.. Can you take a look to this file? http://pastebin.com/ByDnGeWK

Comment: @Drupal8ForTheWin just at first glance, I'm guessing your problem is that you aren't referencing jQuery anywhere, so it's erroring out and none of the document ready stuff is happening

Answer (score 0):

@Phillip Schmidt  : It's working now thx.

I'd like to know if you also have somes knowledges on disable the "classic" scroll ? 
When I scroll on my div, the Zoom work great but the 'classic' scroll too :/